# Django receiver check if first create

Tags: python, django, django-models

The idea of the code below should be that it only fires if the field `verification_pin` is empty i.e. on a new record. However, it seems that every time I save the model it generates a new pin ignoring  `if instance.verification_pin is None` statement, why, what have I missed?

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=CompanyUser)
def my_callback(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.verification_pin is None:
        instance.verification_pin = instance.generate_pin()
        instance.is_active = False
        instance.send_verification_pin()
```

**Model:**

```
class CompanyUser(User):
    verification_pin = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, null=True)
    objects = UserManager()

    def generate_pin(self):
        """
        Returns a random four digit pin.
        """
        return random.randint(999, 9999)

    def send_verification_pin(self):
        self.email_user(
            subject="Test",
            message="Your pin: %s" % self.verification_pin,
            from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
        )
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I think because this is a `pre_save` handler, `instance.save()` is not needed and may cause infinite recursion

Comment: Could you please post ``CompanyUser.generate_pin()`` source code? Maybe it returns and assigns ``None`` to ``instance.verification_pin``.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I sure you don't need to save when using pre_save

Comment: @niekas updated question it sends out the email again also, and runs the generate_pin again.

Comment: probably unrelated, but `max_length` is not a valid option for `IntegerField`

Comment: is the instance perhaps failing to save somewhere else in your code, perhaps the exception is getting caught and ignored?

Comment: have tested your code and it works fine here. are you using the test framework? (it resets the inmemory db between tests)

Answer (score 1):

You can [set the default value for a field to a callable object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default).

Or, you might try using a [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) handler instead, where you can check if `created` is `True`.  Also, it might be helpful to check the value in verification_pin after saving, to see if it really got set or not.